# how to fill rows automaticallyin datagridview in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on vb.net windows application. I have a data grid view like this :
[image]

In this I am not able fill rows to my datagrid view, is there any property to fill rows automatically depend on data grid view size.

Comment: What do you mean by "fill rows automatically"?

Comment: while loading the page i want to get grid view with full row,,here showing some extra space right,,insetd of that i want to show rows

Comment: @user3106114 .. why dont you try to add some blank rows to your datasource ?

Comment: how to add blank rows to datsource??

Comment: you basically want it to look like an Excel file?

Comment: yes sir,,,like EXCEl file only

Comment: there's no property to do that automatically AFAIK

Comment: i can do this by code?

Comment: you can do everything by code but it'd be a waste of time. DGV is not an excel spreadsheet. You could try some 3rd party component like [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Spreadsheet/) or maybe some free ones...